# How to choose between ANOVA and regression?

Tags: regression, anova

I am doing a thesis project evaluating differences in attitudes towards trans students. The only manipulation was which vignette participants read. My variables are as follows:

DV1: First impressions score (continuous)
DV2: Social distance score (continuous)

IV: description of the vignette character: transsexual, cross-dresser, or control.

I also have several potential predictors. Two of which I do not think I have sufficient data to report on (Sexual orientation and religiosity). The others are gender, level of contact (4 categories), and casual attribution (2 categories).

Because I am primarily interested in the differences between groups, I feel as though I should conduct an ANOVA. However, I can't see any straightforward way of incorporating my other predictors into such an analysis. Alternatively, I could run a hierarchical multiple regression to look first at the effect of group and then the other predictors (ordered by theoretical importance). However all my predictors are categorical variables and I'm not really sure how to dummy code to do this properly.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Depending upon the language / tool you're using to do the analysis, this might be very straightforward.  What are you using?  Also, are sexual orientation and religiosity problems because of missing responses?

Comment: ANOVA *is* regression. 
The problem would come in if you want to include relationships between your two DVs.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm using SPSS (PASW 18). jbowman, I'm not sure... I don't think so?? They weren't manipulated so my understanding is that if I don't have enough data to analyze them they are just individual differences. 

Peter, I know that an ANOVA is a form of regression. However they don't have the same assumptions. Also, do I have to alter my categorical variables for them to make sense in a regression?

My two DV's are correlated and I asked a prof about running a MANOVA for instance, but he says the MANOVA is not as robust and won't handle the violated assumptions I have.

Comment: My distributions are skewed in several instances and I do not meet the homogeneity of variances assumption between groups. However my sample size is over 200 (~69 per group) so at least for the ANOVA I should be fine.

Comment: jbowman - I suspect it MAY be straightforward and I am just overthinking it. That's why I'm asking for help! :)

Comment: Ok so I'm aware that I could probably just dump all my variables into one large factorial ANOVA, but I seem to lose power. Does this method in fact reduce significance beyond what would happen if I ran several ANOVAs and adjusted for familywise error?

Comment: For a univariate outcome, option `covb=robust` in SPSS's GENLIN provides robust standard errors, which (for moderate sample sizes) would avoid worrying about non-constant variance. For multivariate outcomes, GEE provides the same general approach, but copes with outcomes being clustered within people. There are various ways GEE can misbehave with binary outcomes, however, so you might want to check over the output with someone experienced.

Comment: Personally I'd just run with a regular regression and report the marginal effects (there's really no difference in the model assumptions, except perhaps that (M)AN(C)OVA is more restrictive.  and you report things differently).  The fact that you've manipulated one variable has implications for causal interpretations of regression coefficients, but not really for choosing a model fitting algorithm, which is basically what you're asking.  Dummy out the controls any way find easy to report afterwards (baseline coding is often the easiest).

Comment: You note that your DVs are correlated, but the question is whether they are correlated *conditional on your covariates*, which in the absence of external information you can only tell by fitting the model and looking.  (It's like normality: models assume conditional not marginal normality).

Comment: Don't worry so much about the name of the analysis, worry about the scientific question. R has a function called `lm` that should do what you want. I'm sure it also has functions for creating matrices of dummy variables; it may even do that under the hood for you so you don't have to build the design matrix yourself. A linear model is a linear model no matter what names you give its special cases ;)